# Python coding in ns3 fails in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine. I installed ns3 to my computer according to instructions in nsnam. I didn't get any errors up to here. I am trying to use python to run my code. I installed python 2.7.3 and ./waf --pyrun examples/first.py doesn't run. I googled a lot I couldnt find any answer why it fails. Here is the config.log for my error:

```
from /home/shaul/tarballs/ns3/ns-3.13/bindings/python: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaul/tarballs/ns3/ns-3.13/.waf-1.6.7-0a94702c61504c487a251b8d0a04ca9a/waflib/Tools/c_config.py", line 435, in run_c_code
    bld.compile()
  File "/home/shaul/tarballs/ns3/ns-3.13/.waf-1.6.7-0a94702c61504c487a251b8d0a04ca9a/waflib/Build.py", line 193, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error)
BuildError: Build failed
 -> task failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 169552396: cxxprogram test.cpp.1.o -> testprog}
['/usr/bin/g++', 'test.cpp.1.o', '-o', '/home/shaul/tarballs/ns3/ns-3.13/build/.conf_check_9a1d0551212c9d703363e62dfbc51c79/testbuild/testprog', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-L/usr/lib', '-lpython2.7', '-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions', '-Wl,-z,relro']

not found
from /home/shaul/tarballs/ns3/ns-3.13/bindings/python: The configuration failed


# try again with -L$python_LIBPL (some systems don't install the python library in $prefix/lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

The instructions via nsnam tell you to download the source and build it: that's not the best way to do it on Ubuntu 12.04.  Ubuntu 12.04 has a package all built for you:

```
sudo apt-get install ns3
```

should do the trick.  No fuss at all.